# speed up heatmap and error in aheatmap (NMF package) when providing a hclust object

Tags: r

I try to speed up my heatmap creation and the main plan was to use `hcluster` function from `amap` package for parallelising the clustering.

I read in `aheatmap` documentation, I can provide a `hclust`-object and I read somewhere on stack overflow, the hierarchical clustering was the main bottle neck. So I wanted to calculate the clustering just once and provide it to my heatmap.

Now I get the following error:

> Error in cluster_mat(mat, Rowv, distfun = distfun, hclustfun = hclustfun,  : 
>     aheatmap - Invalid clustering function: must be a character string or a function

```
pg_h <- matrix(rnorm(10000),ncol = 10)

d <- dist(pg_h)
h <- hclust(d)
aheatmap(pg_h, 
         Colv=NA,
         scale='row',
         distfun=d, 
         hclustfun=h)
```

Can anyone help me with this or is there a different way to create my heatmap. I have around 8000 rows and 15 columns and this takes more than an hour. I only want to cluster the rows.

Answer (score 1):

At least for the error, I believe you have to pass the method obtained from your `hclust` class object (`h`) in this case, like so:

```
aheatmap(pg_h, 
     Colv=NA,
     scale='row',
     distfun=d, 
     hclustfun=h$method)
```

For the following:

[image]

You can see the `method` in the `str` of the object in question:

```
> str(h)
#List of 7
#$ merge      : int [1:999, 1:2] -778 -321 -191 -549 -133 -176 -94 -514 -653 -359 ...
#$ height     : num [1:999] 0.914 0.927 0.934 0.951 0.963 ...
#$ order      : int [1:1000] 74 910 12 864 979 849 218 361 478 974 ...
#$ labels     : NULL
#$ method     : chr "complete"
#$ call       : language hclust(d = d)
#$ dist.method: chr "euclidean"
#- attr(*, "class")= chr "hclust"
```

As for the first part of the question (speeding up, and if this is what you are referring to), passing the method via an `hclust` object *does* seem to produce the output faster. Here are  some benchmarks:

```
system.time(aheatmap(pg_h, Colv=NA, scale='row', distfun=d, hclustfun=h$method))
#   user  system elapsed 
#   3.31    0.36    3.87 
system.time(aheatmap(pg_h, Colv=NA, scale='row', distfun=d, hclustfun="complete"))
#   user  system elapsed 
#   3.51    0.65    4.35
```

Note that the method for hclustfun ("complete") is the same one in both cases.